# Can subnets be tagged (besides notes)?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

getTagReferences service of SoftLayer_Tag makes it very clear which [objects may be tagged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrSjy.jpg). Is it possibly (or will it be possible in the future) to tag subnets other than the notes section?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set tags for Network Subnets.

You can sent an email to PortalFeedback@softlayer.com, in order that this option can be considered to be implemented.