# How can I identify my subnet after creation, if I failed to store the ID?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

There was a question a while back about tagging subnets: [Can subnets be tagged (besides notes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079728/can-subnets-be-tagged-besides-notes)
Is this still the case?

If so, is there any other way I can add something to identify my subnet when I order it? (Just in case my application dies before it has recorded the subnet ID, I'd like a way to check if I've already ordered the subnet I was intending to order, and not accidentally order a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create tags, the only way that I can suggest to track or identify the subnet could be through: **createDate** or **endPoint** that you provided in the order.

Also, you can send an email (**PortalFeedback@softlayer.com**) or submit a ticket with your requirements